# Mariadb fulltext match two columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariasql

I have problem, with my query syntax:

```
SELECT `users`.`name`, `posts`.*
FROM `posts` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST('search')
```

The `MATCH` is working with one only, no both ... please take me advice how to fix it ...

Comment: `AGAINSTa`? Do you want it "OR"-wise or "AND"-wise?

Comment: sorry AGAINST .. I need search in column title and body both columns

Comment: Yes, but should **both** columns match `'search'`? Or is **one** sufficient?

Comment: both ............

Comment: select `users`.`name`, `posts`.* from `posts` left join `users` on `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where MATCH (posts.title) 
AGAINST (+'%divo%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH (posts.body) AGAINST (+'%divo%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Answer (score 1):

To check for `"search"` being in *both* the `title` and `body`, I recommend this un-obvious combination.  (I leave out `users` as being irrelevant to the question.)

```
SELECT  p1.*
    FROM  posts AS p1
    WHERE  MATCH(p1.title) AGAINST("search" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  posts AS p2
            WHERE  MATCH(p2.body) AGAINST("search" IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                  )
```

When using `FULLTEXT`, I don't think the optimizer knows how to efficiently apply FULLTEXT twice, so this is a sneaky way to get it to do so.

I picked `title` first on the assumption that it has fewer words, hence has less need to proceed to the other test.

It *may* be that "index merge intersect" will kick in for this:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  posts
    WHERE  MATCH(title) AGAINST("search" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      AND  MATCH(body)  AGAINST("search" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

In *both* cases, you need *both*:

```
FULLTEXT(title),
FULLTEXT(body)
```

A single ft index with both columns is not useful.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if you need to discuss further.

It possibly matters whether you have `ENGINE=MyISAM` or `ENGINE=InnoDB`; the two implementations are totally different.